# Css apply margin to a table inside a div

Tags: html, css

I have a situation similar to the one represented in [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/x6ukeazd/), 
where there is a table with

```
table {
    width: 100%;
    margin-right: 30px;
}.
```

inside a `div`.

The problem is that when I apply the margin to the table, it goes out of its parent div. How can I avoid that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a `padding-right` on the div instead :

```
div {
    padding-right: 30px;
}
table {
    width: 100%;
}
```

[demo](https://jsfiddle.net/ow44xcfe/1/)

Answer (score 0):

The width applies to the actual content of the element, so you have a table with 100% wide content, and on left of that you add some margins pushing the width over 100%, thus the right side of the table extends beyond the parent's right edge. Probably you should go with padding on the parent instead of margin on the table, or an additional wrapper  with just the margin.

```css
table {
    width: 100%;
    border:1px solid green;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
.inner{
    margin-left:100px;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <div class="inner">
    <table border="1">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>HEADER 1</th>
                <th>HEADER 2</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>11</td>
                <td>12</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>21</td>
                <td>22</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
        </div>
</div>
```